# Manipulate URL after creating per TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, realurl

Is there a way to manipulate an URL after creating per TYPO3 v6.1?

What I want to reach:

I have a Website with an overview page and subpages and if a subpage is clicked, it will be redirected to the parent page with an hash appended (needed for http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html):

```
Overview
- Sub 1
- Sub 2
- Sub 3
```

The shrewd will be, that the site will be multilanguage. Which means, there have to been diffrent redirects to set in the htaccess, which I want do avoid.

What I want to reach is, that the user can link to this page normally and the rest will be done by TYPO3. So I think there could be an configuration in RealURL which recognize the page ID and set the link like overview/sub-1.html#filter=.sub-1

Does anybody know if I can reach this with RealURL or any TypoScript settings? At least can I set a hook?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with typoscript, although I doubt that it's a good idea. Read in [the docs](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.2.0/view/1/10/) ([or v6.1](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/CommonItemStates/Index.html)) how to use the `USERDEF1` menu state in combination with `itemArrayProcFunc` and `submenuObjSuffixes`.

But if this whole functionality is just a javascript enhancement for some feature on you website, then consider adding/modifying the links also with javascript. This way, the "normal" functionality will still work, even with javascript disabled. This is called "[progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)".

Comment: Thanks for the tips at all for "progressive enhancement" ;) But this will be a realy cool feature. And I also want to define links defined in the editor, so that the user don't have to do something. I just found the userFunc in the realURL config. I just check if this will be the solution. At this time I'll miss the referer page ID.